# can't change title from dialog

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I can't change the title from this dialog:

```
var myDialog = dijit.byId('myDialog_'
                     + self["index"]);

            if (!myDialog) {

                //setting date for the dialog

                endTime = new Date();
                var endDate = endTime.customFormat("#DD#.#MM#.#YYYY#");
                startTime = new Date(endTime.getTime() - (endTime.getHours() * 3600000) - (endTime.getMinutes() * 60000) - (endTime.getSeconds() * 1000) - 518400000); //one week
                var startDate = startTime.customFormat("#DD#.#MM#.#YYYY#");

                myDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
                        id : 'myDialog_' + self["index"],
                        title : 'Chart ' + _params.chartTitle
                         + " vom " + startDate + " bis "
                         + endDate,
                        style : 'width:820px;height:500px;'
                    });
                //destroy objects after closing the dialog
                myDialog.connect(myDialog, "hide", function (e) {
                    myDialog.destroy();
                    //graph.destroy();
                    dojo.destroy(trafficLight);
                    dijit.byId("selectVK_" + self["index"]).destroy();
                    dijit.byId("selectTime_" + self["index"]).destroy();
                });
            }
```

I tried this:

```
dojo.byId('myDialog_' + self["index"]).title ="test";
```

but nothing happend... And I tried this:

```
dojo.byId("myDialog_" + self["index"]).set( 'title', "huhu");
myDialog.set( 'title', "huhu");
dojo.byId(myDialog).set( 'title', "huhu");
```

where I always get the error, that set() is not a function...
any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the dijit to set the title

```
dijit.byId("myDlg").set("title", "new title");
```

or

```
dijit.registry.byId("myDlg").set("title", "new title");
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/QWEzC/160/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dialog instance too:

```js
myDialog.set("title", "new title");
```